# Make a AVG of COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning I will need help I test several methods but none of them work I would like to have the result as an average. Knowing that they are COUNTs of two separate tables with columns not having the same name.

```
use prj;
SELECT gender, COUNT(*) 
FROM client    
GROUP BY gender
UNION ALL 
SELECT gendertraveler, COUNT(*) 
FROM othertraveler    
GROUP BY gendertraveler
ORDER BY gender;
```

[Here is the result of this SQL code:]

[image: 1]

[Data from the client table :]

[image: 2]

[Data from the otherclient table :]

[image: 3]

I’d like to have an average of the number of man and woman. Who’s on those two tables.

SQL : https://pastebin.com/3kt6GtRy

Comment: please sample data and desired output

Comment: "*I test several methods but none of them work*" Can you provide these attempts as [mcve]s?

Comment: *but none of them work* Your words contradicts your screenshot which proves that the query works and gives an output. Maybe the output is not one you want simply?

Comment: When I mean none works I’m talking about methods to get an average here I just get the number of values that are in the columns

Comment: Sample data as a screenshot is interesting to nobody. Post textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: When I mean none works I’m talking about methods to get an average here I just get the number of values that are in the columns

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Please don't use screenshots for pure text data

Comment: I just want to have AVG after the count

Comment: The average of what? Please show the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I’d like to have an average of the number of man and woman.

```
select gender , avg(cnt)
from (
    SELECT gender, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM client    
    GROUP BY gender
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT gendertraveler, COUNT(*) 
    FROM othertraveler    
    GROUP BY gendertraveler
) t
group by gender 
order by gender;
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working I will be able to adapt it for my other requests

Answer (score 0):

What I gathered from your two tables, are that the tables of yours are linked to each other via the idclient column.  I would use JOIN's:

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(*)
FROM client    
LEFT JOIN othertraveler ON othertraveler.idclient = client.idclient
GROUP BY gender
ORDER BY gender
```

(The above worked in SQL Server)

- LEFT JOIN if you want to count ALL clients, irregardless of whether
  they are have a foreign key in the othertraveler table or not.
- INNER JOIN if you want to count only the clients that has a foreign key in the
  othertraveler table.